# latex beamer class: links invisible

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I use `\cite{...}` and `\href{...}{...}` in my `beamer` presentation.
The stange thing is that in both cases, there is no colored box around the references,
as I am used to e.g. for class `article`.
Nevertheless, all links are clickable.
I consider this not very useful,
because if a link is not recognized, the reader will click only by accident.

Who can help me making links visible? Is this a common behavior, or am I alone???

Comment: Please always add a small test document to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Beamer uses links in a lot of places, in head- and footline, in navigations symbols and many more places. Having all of them in boxes would interfere with the theme designs.

If you'd like to use boxes for some links, you can temporarily enable them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begingroup\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}\href{example.com}{text}\endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i like that answer.. 
but i feel, that the author does not feel comfortable with my desire to add boxes. 
Well, I think in any form the reader must recognize links as such.. what to do do you suggest? alert-style?

Comment: @user2609605 The purpose of a presentation is normally not for reading. The presenter will know where the links are and can click on them.

Comment: I sidagree. It could be part of a handout and also the presenter is grateful to know where the links are.. at least i am such a presenter.